# SSRS matrix insert column outside group only shows first value from dataset?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

In SSRS report I have the Matrix with one column groups (i.e. week day name) and row group by `week_date` and `Analysis_Name`. When I render report, it **only** shows like first `DOC_ID` in outside group. Any idea how to show **all** `DOC_ID` code in outside group?

Thanks.

Comment: please check your expression, it must `Fields!Value.Value` not the `First(Fields!Value.Value,"datasetname")`

Comment: yes, i have changed to Fields!Value.Value but it not work

Comment: create another group for the DOC_ID

Comment: But group of doc id will remove duplicate ID